# Copy Selected Files To a folder

Tags: java, file-io

I want to copy some selected files to a Destination folder using core java. I cannot use JDK 7. I am using JDK 1.6. Copying the entire source Folder to the destination Folder isn't acceptable.

Example :

Folder T contains x number of .gif files. I have to copy (not move) y (out of x) number of .gif image files to a separate folder, say K.

I cannot copy all of T (i.e x files) to K.

How would I do that in JDK 1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FileUtils.copyDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20java.io.FileFilter%29) from [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) , specifying your source, destination, and a filter that indicates to only copy .gif files. The method's documentation includes an example of copying all `.txt` files from one directory to another, so it gets you about 95% of the way there.

Answer (score -2):

@Ryan answer is one. I've not tried that, though.

However, you may want to do just this:
Write a method that takes in the two directory paths, then use the extension to filter which files to copy. Something like this, perhaps:

```
//get all the select files in that folder
File directory[] = source.listFiles();

//iterate through the files
for (File fileName : directory)
{
   //check here: if the extension doesn't match what you want, continue the loop if it doesn't match

    File newFile = new File(destination + fileName);
}
```

I guess this should get the work fairly done.

Comment: This solution has the disadvantage of not being able to handle nested directories and of being wrong. Appending a `File` to `destination` isn't going to do what you want it to. Even if it were, that's the wrong way to build file paths.

Comment: I didn't considered nested directories. Appending File is fairly easy depending on the way the file paths are passed to the method.

Comment: "depending on the way the file paths are passed to the method" <- exactly what you don't want to depend on.